# How come Page content won't align when creating new page with Visual Composer?

Tags: wordpress

For some odd reason when I create a new page with Visual Composer my content doesn't align at all, however when I edit an existing page that came with a template It does. Video Demonstration:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1LFcmUs1tg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page has the following markup:

```
<div class="no-container stripe-video-content">
    <div class="vc_col-sm-8 wpb_column column_container  ">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                    <h3 class="headline text-left underline  " style="color: #666666">
            About Us        </h3>

    <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>

        </div> 
    </div> 
        </div> 
    </div> 

    <div class="vc_col-sm-4 wpb_column column_container  ">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                    <h3 class="headline text-left  " style="color: #666666">
            Stuff we do best        </h3>
    <div class="vc_progress_bar wpb_content_element default small"><div class="vc_single_bar bar_grey"><small class="vc_label">Development</small><span style="width: 90%;" class="vc_bar" data-percentage-value="90" data-value="90"></span></div><div class="vc_single_bar bar_grey"><small class="vc_label">Design</small><span style="width: 80%;" class="vc_bar" data-percentage-value="80" data-value="80"></span></div><div class="vc_single_bar bar_grey"><small class="vc_label">Marketing</small><span style="width: 70%;" class="vc_bar" data-percentage-value="70" data-value="70"></span></div></div>

        </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

which was apparently written by Visual Composer. The problem is coming from the class on the enclosing div: `no-container` which isn't sufficient to trigger Bootstrap to take care of the responsiveness. Therefore, if you can't figure out how to use VC (I don't use it) to create a div with `.container`, then you can use jQuery to remove the `.no-container` and add `.container`.

That code would be:

```
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery( "div .no-container" ).addClass( "container" );
    jQuery( "div .no-container" ).removeClass( "no-container" );
});
</script>
```

You would add that code to bottom of the WYSIWYG, in text mode, on the page in question. Bear in mind, however, that if there are any other divs on that page with the same class `.no-container`, that they will also be affected and that the div you're targeting may then have other layout abberations within it if you add other content and/or elements. When I used my inspector to apply the class, it did come out perfect though.

Also, please be aware that it's best practice to include your scripts by linking to external files. While you may be able to get away with not doing it in this case, if you want to and have the ability to FTP into the site, the code that goes in the WYSIWYG would look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{the_file_path}/mycustomscript.js"></script>
```

where `{the_file_path}` points to wherever you upload the file. And finally the code in the file would look like this:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery( "div .no-container" ).addClass( "container" );
    jQuery( "div .no-container" ).removeClass( "no-container" );
});
```

Comment: So that's how visual composer is built?You must edit the file manually in order for the content to align? Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: That's not how It looks like when I watch the videos of visual composer.

Comment: That's not how it's supposed to work. VC is supposed to write the code for you so that you don't have to worry about it but using tools such as VC has some major drawbacks. Oftentimes, they're unwieldy, quirky, or simply don't do what they advertise. I never got into VC because, after using my first WYSIWYG, I recognized the unpredictability of the results and simply learned to code HTML and CSS instead. It's not very hard and much easier to control. I highly recommend that route, especially since, if you want to code JS, for instance, you only a stone's throw away from coding HTML and CSS.

Comment: Yeah, I completely agree with you. Coding from scratch is the best. I just wanted to try it out.